# nvprof --metrics works with c++ executable but not with fortran executable

Tags: c++, cuda, fortran, nvprof

I am trying to learn CUDA and I am now stuck at running a simple nvprof command.

I am testing a simple script in both C++ and Fortran using CUDA. The CUDA kernels test two different ways of performing a simple task with the intent to show the importance of the branch divergence issue.

When I run
`nvprof --metrics branch_efficiency ./codeCpp.x` (i.e., on the c++ code) the command works but when I try the same thing on the corresponding fortran code, it doesn't. What is curious is that a simple <nvprof ./codeFortran.x> on the fortran executable will show an output, but anything with the <--metrics> flag will not.
Below I paste some info: (note both codes compile fine and do not produce any runtime error).
I am using Ubuntu 20

Anyone can help to understand this issue? Thank you

===================== c++ code

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "cuda.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include "cuda_common.cuh"

// kernel without divergence
__global__ void code_without_divergence(){

   // compute unique grid index
   int gid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

   // define some local variables
   float a, b;
   a = b = 0.0;

   // compute the warp index
   int warp_id = gid/32;

   // conditional statement based on the warp id
   if (warp_id % 2 == 0)
   {
      a = 150.0;
      b = 50.0;
   }
   else
   {
      a = 200.0;
      b = 75.0;
   };
}

// kernel with divergence
__global__ void code_with_divergence(){

   // compute unique grid index
   int gid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

   // define some local variables
   float a, b;
   a = b = 0.0;

   // conditional statement based on the gid. This will force difference
   // code branches within the same warp.
   if (gid % 2 == 0)
   {
      a = 150.0;
      b = 50.0;
   }
   else
   {
      a = 200.0;
      b = 75.0;
   };
}

int main (int argc, char** argv){

   // set the block size
   int size = 1 << 22;

   dim3 block_size(128);
   dim3 grid_size((size + block_size.x-1)/block_size.x);

   code_without_divergence <<< grid_size, block_size>>>();
   cudaDeviceSynchronize();

   code_with_divergence <<<grid_size, block_size>>>();
   cudaDeviceSynchronize();

   cudaDeviceReset();
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;

};
```

================ Fortran code

```
MODULE CUDAUtils
   USE cudafor
   IMPLICIT NONE


   CONTAINS

   ! code without divergence routine
   ATTRIBUTES(GLOBAL) SUBROUTINE code_without_divergence()
      IMPLICIT NONE

      !> local variables
      INTEGER :: threadId, warpIdx
      REAL(KIND=8) :: a,b

      ! get the unique threadID
      threadId =   (blockIdx%y-1) * gridDim%x  * blockDim%x + &
                   (blockIdx%x-1) * blockDim%x + (threadIdx%x-1)

      ! adjust so that the threadId starts from 1
      threadId = threadId + 1

      ! warp index
      warpIdx = threadIdx%x/32

      ! perform the conditional statement
      IF (MOD(warpIdx,2) == 0) THEN
         a = 150.0D0
         b = 50.0D0
      ELSE
         a = 200.0D0
         b = 75.0D0
      END IF

   END SUBROUTINE code_without_divergence

   ! code with divergence routine
   ATTRIBUTES(GLOBAL) SUBROUTINE code_with_divergence()
      IMPLICIT NONE

      !> local variables
      INTEGER :: threadId, warpIdx
      REAL(KIND=8) :: a,b

      ! get the unique threadID
      threadId =   (blockIdx%y-1) * gridDim%x  * blockDim%x + &
                   (blockIdx%x-1) * blockDim%x + (threadIdx%x-1)

      ! adjust so that the threadId starts from 1
      threadId = threadId + 1

      ! perform the conditional statement
      IF (MOD(threadId,2) == 0) THEN
         a = 150.0D0
         b = 50.0D0
      ELSE
         a = 200.0D0
         b = 75.0D0
      END IF

   END SUBROUTINE code_with_divergence
END MODULE CUDAUtils

PROGRAM main
   USE CUDAUtils
   IMPLICIT NONE

   ! define the variables
   INTEGER    :: size1 = 1e20
   INTEGER    :: istat
   TYPE(DIM3) :: grid, tBlock

   ! blocksize is 42 along the 1st dimension only whereas grid is 2D
   tBlock = DIM3(128,1,1)
   grid   = DIM3((size1 + tBlock%x)/tBlock%x,1,1)

   ! just call the module
   CALL code_without_divergence<<<grid,tBlock>>>()
   istat = cudaDeviceSynchronize()

   ! just call the module
   CALL code_with_divergence<<<grid,tBlock>>>()
   istat = cudaDeviceSynchronize()


STOP
END PROGRAM main
```

1. Output of `nvprof --metrics branch_efficiency ./codeCpp.x`

```
=6944== NVPROF is profiling process 6944, command: ./codeCpp.x
==6944== Profiling application: ./codeCpp.x
==6944== Profiling result:
==6944== Metric result:
Invocations                               Metric Name                        Metric Description         Min         Max         Avg
Device "NVIDIA GeForce MX330 (0)"
    Kernel: code_without_divergence(void)
          1                         branch_efficiency                         Branch Efficiency     100.00%     100.00%     100.00%
    Kernel: code_with_divergence(void)
          1                         branch_efficiency                         Branch Efficiency      85.71%      85.71%      85.71%
```

2. Output of `nvprof --metrics branch_efficiency ./codeFortran.x`

```
==6983== NVPROF is profiling process 6983, command: ./codeFortran.x
==6983== Profiling application: ./codeFortran.x
==6983== Profiling result:
No events/metrics were profiled.
```

3. Output of `nvprof ./codeFortran.x`

```
==7002== NVPROF is profiling process 7002, command: ./codeFortran.x
==7002== Profiling application: ./codeFortran.x
==7002== Profiling result:
No kernels were profiled.
            Type  Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
      API calls:   99.82%  153.45ms         2  76.726ms     516ns  153.45ms  cudaLaunchKernel
                    0.15%  231.24us       101  2.2890us      95ns  172.81us  cuDeviceGetAttribute
                    0.01%  22.522us         1  22.522us  22.522us  22.522us  cuDeviceGetName
                    0.01%  9.1310us         1  9.1310us  9.1310us  9.1310us  cuDeviceGetPCIBusId
                    0.00%  5.4500us         2  2.7250us     876ns  4.5740us  cudaDeviceSynchronize
                    0.00%  1.3480us         3     449ns     195ns     903ns  cuDeviceGetCount
                    0.00%     611ns         1     611ns     611ns     611ns  cuModuleGetLoadingMode
                    0.00%     520ns         2     260ns     117ns     403ns  cuDeviceGet
                    0.00%     245ns         1     245ns     245ns     245ns  cuDeviceTotalMem
                    0.00%     187ns         1     187ns     187ns     187ns  cuDeviceGetUuid
```

Both the c++ and Fortran executables test the same CUDA concept. They both compile fine and no runtime errors are shown on the terminal upon execution.
When I try the `nvprof` command on the c++ program, everything works as expected but when I try it on the corresponding fortran program, there is no output (using the `--metrics` flag). I would expect the same behavior obtained with the c++ code.

0
In some other discussions I found that for GPU version above 7, nvprof is no longer supported and NVIDIA Nsight should be used, however i do not think this is the case because i get the expected output with the c++ program.

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour]. Be careful how you format your post, the use of the backticks can be tricky and it made your post formatted in an unreadable way. Always review the result.

Comment: *"however i do not think this is the case because i get the expected output with the c++ program."* This is not a valid argument. Even unsupported tools sometimes work. And sometimes they may not.

Comment: what happens when you run your fortran code with `compute-sanitizer` ?  (`compute-sanitizer ./codeFortran.x`)  are any errors reported?

Comment: Also, your kernel code is such that it will result in an empty kernel due to compiler optimization unless you compile with the `-G` flag.  So if you are compiling your cpp code with `-G`, but not doing the same thing with the fortran code, that could be a factor.  It's not sensible to try and profile a kernel like this.  The kernel doesn't modify any global state and therefore can be completely optimized away.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments. Upon checking, it seems that the problem was related to the `size1` variable in my fortran code, which was too big. Now I get the output of `--metrics branch_efficiency` although both kernels seem to be returning 100% efficiency (whereas the c++ code shows ~85% efficiency for the divergent kernel). I made a step forward. Now I need to understand why I do not get  the same efficiency as the c++ code. Thank you!

Comment: @RoberCrovella, yes I was getting an error using `compute-sanitizer`. Although it was not exactly pointing to the `size1` variable, it helped me to track it down.

Comment: You don't get the same efficiency because your fortran kernels are compiling to an empty kernel.  An empty kernel has no divergent branches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the code was not profiling as expected was that the kernels were not actually running correctly in that case.

It's always good practice to make sure there are no runtime errors with a code before attempting any profiling.  Proper CUDA error checking and `compute-sanitizer` are two methods to help with this.

Comment: when you say “proper CUDA” error check what are you referring to, specifically?

Comment: In CUDA C++ proper CUDA error checking looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api).  In CUDA Fortran it looks like [this](https://docs.nvidia.com/hpc-sdk/compilers/cuda-fortran-prog-guide/#error-handling) and [this](https://docs.nvidia.com/hpc-sdk/compilers/cuda-fortran-prog-guide/#cfapi-runtime). The idea is the same. Every CUDA API call (functions that start with `cuda...` but not `cudafor...`) returns an error code. Don't ignore it. CUDA kernel launches require a particular kind of error trapping.